# Use Automatic Referencing Count in specific classes in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

Actually i came to this question when i was trying to add some classes that have been made upon ios prior to IOS 5 and these classes doesn't having ARC and the project i am trying to add is made upon the IOS 5 and it give me the compile time error related to ARC the classes having suck kind of information that if i try to remove the release/retain then it start behaving irregular.That is my problem, Now come to question i want to know that is there any way so that i can mark those classes not to use ARC so that the newly created classes that having base SDK ios5 compile with ARC and i mention not to use ARC simply compiled with their retain/release values.That is the only way i have left i think for making properly this app.

Any idea how i can use those classes that is having base sdk prior to ios5.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the image below will show you how to do it.

```
-fno-objc-arc   flag to disbale arc 

-fobjc-arc      flag to enable arc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project settings, under Build Phases > Compile Sources
Select the files you want ARC disabled and add -fno-objc-arc compiler flags. You can set flags for multiple files in one shot by selecting the files then hit Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Issue Navigator -> Validate project settings -> Perform changes. In this way Xcode automatically remove release and retain keywords from whole project and convert into ARC compatible.