# How to (Using Storyboard) create JSON Parser in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, json, storyboard, rfc

Currently I am working in iPhone application, Using Storyboard to create JSONParser, Import JSON Library inside the application, then I have add #import JSON/JSON.h inside  ViewController.h file, but the error comes in "file not found", and JSON Framework classes error in release because I am using RFC, so how to fix these issues?

Inside JSON Framework classes error found here

[image: JSON Framework classes error]

Comment: Try to [disable ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) for the SBJson-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project uses ARC, but the JSON library doesn't. You need to disable ARC for the library files. To find out how, see this question:
[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project), or this one: [ios5 ARC what is the compiler flag to exclude a file from ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040629/ios5-arc-what-is-the-compiler-flag-to-exclude-a-file-from-arc)

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting is ARC issue. your project is ARC enabled , but the JSON framework is not using ARC.

you can disable the ARC in your whole project, or use it for single file . [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629820/use-automatic-referencing-count-in-specific-classes-in-ios/9629853#9629853)